# Heap's algorithm checking for odd and even

Tags: algorithm, logic, permutation, factorial, heaps-algorithm

can someone explain why does **Heap's Algorithm** uses a condition statement checking for **K** whether it is even or odd and the swaps are different in each one?
i can't find any intuitive explanation on the Internet

this code is from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)

```
procedure generate(k : integer, A : array of any):
    if k = 1 then
        output(A)
    else
        // Generate permutations with kth unaltered
        // Initially k == length(A)
        generate(k - 1, A)

        // Generate permutations for kth swapped with each k-1 initial
        for i := 0; i < k-1; i += 1 do
            // Swap choice dependent on parity of k (even or odd)
            if k is even then
                swap(A[i], A[k-1]) // zero-indexed, the kth is at k-1
            else
                swap(A[0], A[k-1])
            end if
            generate(k - 1, A)

        end for
    end if
```

Comment: please provide link to where you got the snippet from for better context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really disentangle the reason that you change swapping behavior based on `k`'s parity from the explanation/justification for why the algorithm works as a whole, and that is a complicated thing to demonstrate, but basically, it relates to the different side-effects `generate` has on the underlying array depending on whether `k` is even or odd, and leveraging those side effects in an alternating fashion to explore the whole permutation space. These side-effects and their interactions are a bit mathematically complicated, so, to simplify the discussion, first I'm going to re-write the algorithm into a completely a equivalent form that will be easier to reason about. Rather than putting the first call to `generate` outside of the `for` loop and iterating from 0 to k-1, we put it inside, iterate from 0 to k, and break out of the last iteration early (to avoid unnecessary swaps after all output for the current `k` value has already been generated).

```
procedure generate(k : integer, A : array of any):
  if k = 1:
    output(A)
  else:
    for i := 0; i < k; i += 1 do:
      generate(k - 1, A)
      if i + 1 = k:
        break
      if k is even:
        swap(A[i], A[k-1])
      else:
        swap(A[0], A[k-1])
```

However, letting the unnecessary swaps occur on the tail-end of the final loop iterations by removing the break statement produces the same permutations (albeit in a different order), and makes the side-effects of each iteration of the program significantly easier to reason about:

```
procedure generate(k : integer, A : array of any):
  if k = 1:
    output(A)
  else:
    for i := 0; i < k; i += 1 do:
      generate(k - 1, A)
      if k is even:
        swap(A[i], A[k-1])
      else:
        swap(A[0], A[k-1])
```

With that out of the way, here's the basic idea of Heap's algorithm (in any form):

Calling the generate function with a given `k` value is meant to permute the first k elements of the array (everything from index k and beyond is necessarily fixed, because no swaps involve indices exceeding `k-1`). To permute these first k elements, we're making k recursive calls to `generate(k-1, A)`, and before each of these recursive calls are made, we want to swap a *unique element* from the segment we are permuting to its end (that is into the kth position: index `k-1`), because putting a different element on the back of all size k-1 permutations effectively generates all size k permutations. The conditional choice of where we swap from to pick this unique element is dictated purely by the different side effects calling `generate(k-1, A)` has on the underlying array depending on whether `k-1` is even or odd, but the point is the same: to pick an element we haven't used yet in the `for` loop and swap it back to the kth position of the array before we generate the next batch of size k-1 permutations.

The reason these swaps work in this amended version of the algorithm are actually pretty simple. The side effect of calling `generate(k-1, A)` where `k-1` is even is to rotate those first `k-1` elements of the array one position to the right, and calls to `generate(k-1, A)` with odd `k-1` actually have no side effects in terms of element order: the first `k-1` elements of the array end up exactly where they were before the call was made.

For an example in the even `k` case, if we call `generate(4, A)` successively on the array `[1,2,3,4,5,...]`, the first 4 elements cycle like this (and everything following them is fixed):

```
[1,2,3,4,...]
[4,1,2,3,...]
[3,4,1,2,...]
[2,3,4,1,...]
[1,2,3,4,...]
...
```

If we call `generate(5, A)` on `[1,2,3,4,5,6,...]`, the side effect in terms of the array's order is a no-op (All permutations of the first 5 elements are still being generated from the recursive calls, it's just that the extra swaps made when we remove the break statement cancel out the ordering side effects).

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,...]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,...]
...
```

The conditional swap strategy comes directly out of these facts:

When `k` is even we're calling `generate(k-1, A)` with an odd value, which has no ordering side effect, so if we want to pick a different element each iteration to swap to the back we can just use `swap(A[i], A[k-1])`, as `i` increments each iteration and the other elements aren't moving.

On the other hand, when `k` is odd, we're calling `generate(k-1, A)` with an even value, which has the side effect of rotating elements one step to the right. That is why we simply pull from `A[0]` repeatedly: the side effects of the even calls to `generate` in the loop do the work of cycling elements for us: we can just grab elements from the first position every time because the side-effects put a different element into that position at each iteration.

Basically, if we want to grab every one of the first `k` elements across our `for` loop and they're statically positioned, we have to use every value of `i`, and if they're cycling already, we have to grab from the same position every time. Whether they're statically positioned or cycling already depends on the different ordering side-effects `generate` has based on whether `k` is even or odd. The mathematics of the side-effects for even/odd k, the cycles those side-effects produce, and the reasoning behind why these particular rules work changes a bit when you add the `break` back, but the same rules still work and the general form of the analysis you have to do to prove that also remains the same.